# Is there a way for python to read in datasets in excel generated by an excel function?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl, pywin32

I paste a formula into excel that will generate a dataset in excel. The dataset is successfully generated in excel, but I attempt to read in the excel into python with pd.read_excel, I always got an empty dataset...

I have tried:

1. convert the excel to csv and read in the csv.
2. In Excel, go to Formulas tab, set 'calculation options' to 'automatic'
3. Import Win32, force calculation before saving the workbook in excel.

Here is the code:

```
# import libraries
import openpyxl
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd

# This is not the actual query
excel_query = 'generate_my_dataset' 
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# Write the formula to a cell
worksheet['A1'] = excel_query
workbook.save('my_dataset_1.xlsx')

# Load the workbook
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('my_dataset_1.xlsx')

# Select the active sheet
sheet = workbook.active

# Force recalculation of all formulas
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('my_dataset_1.xlsx')
excel.CalculateFull()

# Save the workbook
wb.Save()
wb.Close()
excel.Quit()

# Save the workbook
workbook.save('my_dataset_2.xlsx')

# Read the recalculated workbook into DataFrame
my_df = pd.read_excel('my_dataset_2.xlsx')`

# Print the DataFrame
print(my_df)`
```

The result is an empty df. I have checked that both my_dataset_1.xlsx and my_dataset_2.xlsx has the dataset I need. However, my_df is empty. Any potential fix for that?

Comment: I'd skip `openpyxl` here completely, write the formula using `win32com` before you calculate. You can create a new workbook with `Workbooks.Add` if necessary.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks so much! Will try now and let you know what happens!

Comment: @BigBen I tried what you suggested but the dataset is not even generated this time... I have confirmed that the formula is working correctly by opening a blank excel sheet and paste it in, and it did generate the dataset I need.... This is so weird... Thanks so much for your help! Any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: Is this a formula from an Excel add-in (e.g. Bloomberg)? Or a native Excel formula?

Comment: It is a formula to generate dataset from my company's database

Comment: Ok but does it use native Excel formulas, or a VBA User-Defined-Function, or what? In other words, how does it start: `=WhatHere?`

Comment: @BigBen it looks like: =@CompanyNameHistoricalPrices('Ticker',Start_date, end_date)

Comment: That doesn't look like a native Excel formula. What add-ins do you have installed? Where I'm going with this: if this formula comes from an add-in, you may have to load that add-in programmatically in Python.

Comment: @BigBen When I open excel with any office PC, it has an extra tab called CompanyLink... Sorry I don't know what add-ins this is...

Comment: Sounds like an internally developed add-in. You can find it under File > Options > Add-ins.

Comment: @BigBen I found it! It's a DNA file called Excel-DNA64

Comment: The openpyxl code does nothing, you can remove it.